# How do I cast rows to typelist in devexpress gridview just like winforms datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, devexpress

I have below code that is working correctly in winforms datagridview but I dont know how to make it work and get same results in devexpress `gridview.columns.cast` works fine but their is no option for `gridview.rows.cast` like in Datagridview of winforms.

I have tried getrow, getdatarow and others but to no avail

```
List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in gridView1.Rows.cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                  where Convert.ToBoolean(gridView1.GetRowCellValue[0].Value) == true
                                                  select row).ToList();
            if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Do you want to delete {0} rows?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
                {
                   ...
                }
             }
```

After foreach their is a sql query that runs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEipB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can loop thru selected rows of a devexpress gridview like this

```
int[] selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
{
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = gttDXGridView1.GetRowCellValue(selectedRows[i], yourColumn) });
   ...
}
```

**by the way, using `AddWithValue` is not always a good idea, see [this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)**

To retrieve it as a datarow, you can try this in the loop

```
int[] selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
{
   DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(selectedRows[i]);

   ...
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = row["Id"] });
   ...
}
```

Unless you need to retrieve more then one value from each row, this would mean an extra step off course

Comment: I need to be able to use multiple values from checkboxed selected rows with sql query as you can see in the image I have attached. I only need a alternative for Rows error.

Comment: It sounds like your GridControl is bound to a  DataTable/DataSet. In that case, you can use the GridView's GetDataRow method to retrieve the entire row as a DataRow object.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image. On SO not everyone can see all images

Comment: you can use the loop I suggested to fill the SqlCommand parameter as in your image, I have edited my answer

Comment: I also added an example of how you can get the entire row, as suggested by @Brendon